# Crash: When accessing vector from class

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I'm programming an ESP32 UI and have run into this issue:

I have a class Menu, and define a vector _menuItemStack in its header.

I create an Object MenuItem from outside and pass it to the function addMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem). It adds it to the stack. Which works, when I declare the vector in the Menu.cpp it runs. But it won't be unique for each object, I think it becomes static?

So I declared the vector as private in the header, while it will compile. it crashes immediately.

What is my mistake? C++ makes my head hurt.

**Menu.h**

```
    /*
  Menu.h - Menu Class
*/
#ifndef Menu_h
#define Menu_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "StackArray.h"
#include "MenuItem.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "U8g2lib.h"

class Menu
{
  public:
    Menu();
    void update();
    void draw();
    void addMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem);
  private:
    int arrayPos;
    std::vector<MenuItem> _menuItemStack;
};

#endif
```

**Menu.cpp**

```
#include "Menu.h"
extern U8G2_SSD1327_MIDAS_128X128_2_4W_HW_SPI u8g2;

Menu::Menu() {
  arrayPos = 0;
}

void Menu::draw() {

  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_6x10_tf);

  int posY = 0;

  for (MenuItem &m : _menuItemStack){
    u8g2.drawStr(0,posY+15,m.getText().c_str());
    posY+=15;
  }
}
void Menu::update() {

}

void Menu::addMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem){
  arrayPos++;
  _menuItemStack.push_back(menuItem);

  //debug
  Serial.println(arrayPos);
  Serial.println(menuItem.getText());
}
```

Notes: the std::stdlib is included higher up.

EDIT:

MenuItem.cpp

```
#include "MenuItem.h"
extern U8G2_SSD1327_MIDAS_128X128_2_4W_HW_SPI u8g2;

MenuItem::MenuItem() {
  _text = new String;
}

MenuItem::MenuItem(const MenuItem &obj){
  _text = new String;
  *_text = *obj._text;
}

void MenuItem::draw(){

}
void MenuItem::update(){

}

void MenuItem::setText(String txt){
  *_text = txt;
}

String MenuItem::getText(){
  return *_text;
}

void MenuItem::attachHandler(CallbackFunction f){
  callback = f;
}

void MenuItem::run(){
  if (callback != NULL) callback();
}
```

MenuItem.h

```
#ifndef MenuItem_h
#define MenuItem_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "StackArray.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "U8g2lib.h"

class MenuItem
{
  private:
    typedef void (*CallbackFunction)();
    CallbackFunction callback = NULL;
    String *_text;
  public:
    MenuItem();
    MenuItem(const MenuItem &obj);
    void draw();
    void update();
    void run();
    void setText(String txt);
    void attachHandler(CallbackFunction f);
    String getText();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Does it crash if you don't draw?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `std::vector::push_back` you create a copy of your object and store it into the vector. So first check, the copy constructor of your class and if the error could be caused by this.

Then you need to know where is stored the memory necessary for `std::vector`.

On embedded target you may not be using the traditional standard library and manipulating memory can be tricky.

When you declare your vector as a global variable, it is highly probable that the memory required is not in the same zone than when you declare it as a private member of a class. This will depend on your platform, compiler, linker script, and the lib C++ your are using. `std::vector` use an allocator, on Linux you can get away without looking at what it does, when on embedded target you need to know which allocator your are using and where the memory is.

You can try to print the address of `std::vector::data()` to check that. Then you will probably have to either provide your own allocator or to reserve a portion of memory large enough to hold the vector and initialize the data contained in your vector at this memory address.

Answer (score 0):

The `menuItem` passed into the `addMenuItem` function is a copy that has a lifespan until the end of that function.

Try passing in the menu item as a reference so that your list of menu items will be populated with objects that have a lifespan longer than the `addMenuItem` function. That change the signature to look like this:

```
void Menu::addMenuItem(MenuItem& menuItem)
```

Comment: Hey, changing it to reference, doesn't make it crash. However now my copy constructor doesn't seem to be passing the correct values. I added it to the code above.